# How to specific a output file when converting from version 1 to version 2

Tags: c#, api, vue.js, postman, postman-collection

Currently I was given a collection for postman, but it is using version 1 so I need to convert it to version 2 by using the plugin postman developed which [this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/#converting-postman-collections-from-v1-to-v2).

I followed exactly what they wrote and followed the command they gave but still is displaying this

[image: Here is the image] 
[image: I also tried to write the full directory] 
[image: Here is the file that I am using]

May know I why it is not reading my the output file that I already inserted.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Those Link is the images of the response, why i can't emended it is because You're not allowed to embed images in your posts yet, so we've included a link instead.

As soon as you earn 10 reputation on the site, you'll be able to embed images.

Comment: of course I know that. You must copy the command and output text and past them here. The parts that are image will be edited by people with enough reputation. Did you ever read that link? Images are hard to read, almost impossible to search or copy, doesn't zoom or wrap well and difficult for blind people

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors in your command (e.g. using `-input` instead of `--input` or keeping the `<>`), here's an example from [the official GitHub repository](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-collection-transformer):

```
$ postman-collection-transformer convert \
--input ./v1-collection.json \
--input-version 2.0.0 \
--output ./v2-collection.json \
--output-version 1.0.0 \
--pretty \
--overwrite
```

I'd recommend using this one replacing the values you need.